# Tunnelblick OpenVPN IP Not Being Changed

Tags: macos, vpn, openvpn

I am using `Tunnelblick 3.5beta08 (build 4236)` on `OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)`. My OpenVPN configuration file:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote XXX XXX
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 5
redirect-gateway def1
```

It connects fine and gives me the interface:

```
$ ifconfig tap0
tap0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 82:96:bc:08:30:95
    inet 10.0.0.22 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
    open (pid 67113)
```

Unfortunately I get the warning that my external IP has not changed and checking it in my browser this is indeed true. How do I get my external IP to change? (warning I'm new to VPNs)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a simple one: while disconnected from any connection through TunnelBlick, click on ”VPN details” -> click the specific connection that you want to use and then on SETTINGS. 
There, make sure that you've checked the ”Route all IPv4 traffic through the VPN”. After that, just click the CONNECT button.

Comment: That was it. I was looking for a way to set it up in the config file though but this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

## My client conf file:

```
client
dev tun
remote xx.xx.xx.xx
port 1194
proto udp
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
comp-lzo
nobind
route-delay 1 3
redirect-gateway def1
```

**In OS X Terminal - disable ipv6 if you're not using it:**

Turning off IPv6 support for ethernet:

```
networksetup -setv6off Ethernet
```

or

Disabling IPv6 for wireless:

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

source:  http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/18/disable-ipv6-mac-os-x/

```
In Tunnelblick --> VPN Details...: --> Set nameserver (3.0b10)
```

This settings worked for me in OS X El Capitan Public Beta 6

Comment: Sorry but I have since ditched my Mac in favor of Linux. I can no longer check this issue. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: I'm able to perform all of the steps above on macOS Sierra, but it does not resolve the IP address issue for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this and was able to fix it by changing from a tun to tap connection.

- To do this, change your line "dev tun" to "dev tap" and make sure you update the port as your VPN server likely uses a different port for tap vs. tun. This will change your IP but in my experience doesn't let me network with the other computers on the network so I have 2 configurations, one if I want to connect to the local network computers and leave my IP alone (tun) and one if I want to route all my browsing through home network but not connect to local machines (tap).

Comment: But the OP’s config file already says ``dev tap`` — what should they do?